# How can I map fields from 2 input to generate 1 output

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have two input 1° data from Access DB retrieving a data table "names of students and details" 2° input SQL data base a table containing scores

I would like to know if there a possibility to graphically map fields from input 1 to input 2 "a student matched to his score" and finally generate an Excel file containing a table concatenate student and the reference of the column that contain the score "table name cell reference or number fully qualified column reference consists of the table name, a period, and then the column name I don't know..."

FYI: I did retrieve data from both access as Microsoft access input and data base as table input as shown in the picture below

2 input access and DB => 1 output after mapping fields as Excel

[image]

Comment: Before going on with the Answer, i need to know if both inputs have "keys" on which to match the rows from both inputs, like an Enrollment Number or some other form of info.

Comment: you can use merge join or stream look up step if both input have key like enrolment number or seat number.